# Android - save photo to path - RESULT_CANCELLED

Tags: android

Since I had bugs on different devices I decided to changed the whole open camera and save picture code. I have used the exact same code in the [Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html).

My code:

```
private static File createImageFile(Activity activity) throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    photoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}

private static void dispatchTakePictureIntent(Activity activity) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = MainActivity.createImageFile(activity);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                    "com.APPPACKAGE.fileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

On the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
android:maxSdkVersion="18" />

<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.APPPACKAGE.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Using this works great on a Android 6 Marshmallow, on Android 4.4 Kitkat it doesn't. On Kitkat my `onActivityResult` i recieve from the camera `result = 0` which is `RESULT_CANCELLED`.

I've checked if the camera was able to save the photo on the location specified in the `file_paths.xml` and it didn't. this folder is filled with 0 bytes files.

What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @CommonsWare i added this code and it works:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                ClipData clip=
                        ClipData.newUri(activity.getContentResolver(), "A photo", imageUri);

                takePictureIntent.setClipData(clip);
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            }
            else {
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
                        activity.getPackageManager()
                                .queryIntentActivities(takePictureIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    activity.grantUriPermission(packageName, imageUri,
                            Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not all camera apps will support `content` as a scheme for the `EXTRA_OUTPUT` `Uri`. Google's own camera app did not support it until the summer of 2016, for example. And, since we are passing the `Uri` via an extra, we have no means of limiting ourselves to camera apps that support `content`.

Your main options are:

1. Reduce your `targetSdkVersion` below 24 and stick with `Uri.fromFile()`, rather than using `FileProvider`
2. Use `StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().build());` to disable the `FileUriExposedException`, then stick with `Uri.fromFile()`, rather than using `FileProvider`
3. Scrap your use of `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` entirely, switching to the camera APIs directly or via some helper library (e.g., [mine](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2))

Tactically, you might get better results if you [use `setClipData()` to force granting of permissions on your `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/31/granting-permissions-uri-intent-extra.html).